# Intersecting more than two layers at same time using QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, intersection, expression, virtual-layer

**Background:**

At 3.20.3, there are two intersect tools available: ***Vector > Geoprocessing tools >  Intersection*** and ***Processing Toolbox > SAGA > Features - Polygons > Intersect.***

In both cases, only two layers can be intersected at a time.  However, I have numerous layers that need to be intersected, and it would be much more efficient to conduct the task once, rather than two-at-a-time.

I notice that the Advanced ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.1 ***Intersection*** tool allows more than two input layers.  I've searched the internet, plugins, and the documentation without success for a similar QGIS solution.

**Question:**

How do I intersect more than two layers at a time using QGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer: the principles

You can use QGIS expressions to generate custom overlay like intersection of as many layer as you want. Use [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html#hard-fa-geometry-generator-symbology) or [Geoemtry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) (see [here for differences](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)).

## How to do it

Let's say you have 5 polygon layers, name `p1` to `p5`. Say you look for the areas where all five intersect. Split up this task in several steps. This is because the expression `intersect()` only takes two arguments (input layers), so you have to create a "nested" (combined) statement, say like (pseudocode):

```
intersect the (interesction of A and B) with the (interesction of C and D)
```

Or more detailed:

1. Intersection of p2 with p3 (lines 4-7 in the expression below)
2. Intersection of p4 with p5 (lines 8-11)
3. Intersect the result of steps 1 and 2 (you get: intersection of layers p2, p3, p4 and p5)
4. Intersect p1 with the result of step 3.

## The expression to use

The expression looks like this (see below at the bottom for detailed explanation of the functions used):

```
intersection (
    $geometry, 
    intersection (
        intersection (
            buffer (collect_geometries(overlay_intersects('p2', $geometry)),0), 
            buffer (collect_geometries (overlay_intersects( 'p3', $geometry)),0)
        ),
        intersection (
            buffer (collect_geometries(overlay_intersects('p4', $geometry)),0), 
            buffer (collect_geometries (overlay_intersects( 'p5', $geometry)),0)
        )
    )
)
```

*Screenshot: the expression with Geometry generator: the diagonal X hached area is created with the expression above - the area where all 5 layers intersect:*

[image]

## Variant: how to adapt the expression to changing number of layers

For an even number of intersecting polygons, adapt the expression as follows (here: 6 polygons `p1` to `p6`). As you see, I added a `buffer([geometry],0)` statement. Sometimes, without this, the expression returns `NULL`.

```
intersection (
    intersection (
        buffer (collect_geometries (overlay_intersects ('p5',$geometry)),0), 
        buffer (collect_geometries (overlay_intersects ('p6',$geometry)),0)
    ),
    intersection (
        intersection (
            buffer (collect_geometries (overlay_intersects ('p4',$geometry)),0), 
            buffer (collect_geometries (overlay_intersects ('p3',$geometry)),0)
        ),
        intersection(
            $geometry, 
            collect_geometries (overlay_intersects ('p2',$geometry))
        )
    )
)
```

*Screenshot: the diagonal X hached area, representing the common space of all 6 polygons, is bordered by all 6 polgons as you can see from the color of the outer boundaries: red, blue, green, yellow, black and pink:*
[image]

## Explanation: How this expression works

- The intersection is done using the [`intersection()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#intersection) function, this only takes two arguments: `intersection(geometry1, geometry2)`.
- So we have to combine intermediate steps with nested (combined) `intersection` functions. Geometry generator as well as Geoemtry by expression are always based on a specific layer, so to get the geometries of the other layers to combine (intersect) them, we use the [`overlay_intersect()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#overlay-intersects) function.
- This returns an *array* of all geometries, so to get geometries, we must convert from array to geometries using [`collect_geometries()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#collect-geometries).
- To work properly, we must buffer these geometries by 0, using [`buffer()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#buffer) function. For the very layer we work on, it's enough to get the geometries with [`$geometry`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#geometry).

Comment: This is *very* interesting!  I just successfully tried it with five layers, using *Geometry Generator*.  Now I want to use *Geometry by Expression* to create an output layer using six input layers.  Since I'm not much of a programmer, how would your code be modified for an even number of input layers?

Comment: The expression works the same also with Geoemtry by expression - just copy/paste, no need to program something.

Comment: Here's where I'm confused: The *Geometry by Expression* tool starts with one input layer.  Then your code works with the remaining layers to be intersected in *pairs*.  That means that there must be an *odd* number of total layers to be intersected (the required input layer, plus the pairs).  However, in my case, there is an *even* number of layers to be intersected.  How do I modify your code to accommodate an even number of layers to be intersected?

Comment: Added a version using the intersection of 6 polygons: does that help? Also added a `buffer()` statement (buffering with 0) as without this, it doesn't always work properly.

Comment: Yes, this helps!  Some comments: 1) I added a buffer() statement to the last line (the P2 layer), for consistency, and it works fine.  2) You can simply change the term *intersection* with *union* and Voila!  3) How to include overlay attribute fields?  The only fields in the output layer are those from P1.  I'll need to include fields from the overlay layers.  Thoughts?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how you modified the code for a different number of input layers.  I tried to adapt your 6-input code for 4-input by deleting lines 2 - 5, but the expression editor gave an error, expecting a different number of intersections.  I'm confused...

Comment: Delete lines 1 to 5 and the very last line, the closing bracket `)`, then it should work.

Comment: For adding attributes, better use a virtual layer - see new answer.

Answer (score 1):

As your initial question focused on intersection only, without attributes, my first answer did just that. As you specified later, you're interested in the attributes as well. So this is best done using a virtual layer, based on the same principles: as `st_intersection()` takes just two arguments, you have to combine several `st_intersection()` statements.

To create a new layer with the common area of four layers `p1` to `p4` plus all attributes, use this query in the dialog creating the ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`:

```sql
select
    st_intersection(st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry), st_intersection(c.geometry, d.geometry)),
    *
from
    p1 as a, p2 as b, p3 as c, p4 as d
```

*Screenshot: the hatched area in pink is the area where all four layers intersect. It's created as a virtual layer. As you can see from the attribute tables, it does not only create the geometry, but also adds all attributes, thanks to the `, *` statement at the end of the first line:*
[image]